# Two similar assembly code. A Substantial difference

Tags: optimization, x86

I have Ivy-Bridge CPU.
The following code takes 3 cycle per iteration:

```
L1:    
    movapd xmm1, [rsi+rax] ; X[i], X[i+1]
    mulpd xmm1, xmm2
    movapd xmm0, [rdi+rax] ; Y[i], Y[i+1]
    subpd xmm0, xmm1
    movapd [rdi+rax], xmm0 ; Store result
    add rax, 16
    cmp rax, rcx
    jl L1
```

The following takes 9 cycles per iteration:

```
L1:
    movapd xmm1, [rsi+rax] ; X[i], X[i+1]
    mulpd xmm1, xmm2
    movapd xmm0, [rdi+rax] ; Y[i], Y[i+1]
    add rax, 16
    subpd xmm0, xmm1
    movapd [rdi+rax], xmm0 ; Store result
    cmp rax, rcx
    jl L1
```

The only difference is order ( `add rax, 16`). And it causes that the program is 3 times slower. Why the difference is so substantial?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main reason is that it stores the result in a different location, which also happens to be the location read by the next iteration of the loop.

Doing that interferes with the CPU's out-of-order execution -- the next iteration of the loop can't start until the current iteration completes, due to the data dependency.

I would imagine if you change the store instruction to store back to the same location, the second loop would become substantially faster again:

```
movapd [rdi+rax-16], xmm0 ; Store result
```

Comment: "I would imagine if you change the store instruction to store back to the same location, the second loop would become substantially faster again:"
You right! :)

The my question is:

why `add rax, 16` doesn't make slower? After all we have dependency:    `movapd [rdi+rax-16], xmm0` must be followed by `add rax, 16` because we change value of `rax`. Maybe Register Renaming plays role here?

Comment: Well, the latency of an integer add is pretty small (1 cycle)?  More importantly, there's no dependency involving the xmm instructions in the net iteration of the loop, so they can all start while the store is still pending.  Its the interference with those instructions that causes the slowdown in the slow case.

Answer (score 4):

They have a substantially different dependency structure.

With the moved `add rax, 16`, now the place the result is written back to is the next item. So in the next iteration, it reads what it just wrote there, and so on.

So now all of a sudden there is a loop-carried dependency of `movapd xmm0, .. \ subpd \ movapd [next], xmm0`, which has a latency of 9 cycles on Ivy (3 per instruction as it happens).

Before, the only loop-carried dependency was the trivial one on `rax`.

Comment: "which has a latency of 9 cycles on Ivy (3 per instruction as it happens)."
Why 9? From what I can see in manual latency is 3 cycle. 
"Before, the only loop-carried dependency was the trivial one on rax."

Yes, indeed. How does make it slower our loop? - If we had not this dependency our iteration would take X cycles.

What is X?

Comment: @Gilgamesz there are three instructions there, each with a latency of 3, so 9 in total. I don't understand your other question

Comment: Did you mean `subpd xmm0, xmm1`, ` movapd [rdi+rax], xmm0`, `movapd xmm0, [rdi+rax]`?
Second question again ( sorry for my English) :
I consider how to interpret the fact that in the original code ( faster case) there is also data dependency between iteration: `add rax, 16`